# How to upgrade project server 2013 database after SharePoint 2013 upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

I have installed MS Project Server 2013 on top of SharePoint server 2013

after installing some cumulative updates for SharePoint from Microsoft

when I run psconfig to upgrade my system it fails and give blow error

```
    Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
04/18/2015 13:29:32.79  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxmn   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_f8326d3c-d849-47c... 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:32.79  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxmn   WARNING Exception occured when querying old feature with id [29e9a673-31a4-46a3-b0d2-d8e1db1dbd92], skipping. Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Failed to find the XML file at location '15\Template\Features\NintexLiveAdminLinks\feature.xml'     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPXmlDocCache.GetGlobalXmlDocument(String pathTemplateRelativeXml, SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Int32 compatibilityLevel)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarmFeatureDefinitionContext.LoadFileAsXmlDocument(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, String featureRelativePath)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_Scope()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateFeaturesTable(StringBuilder sqlstr)  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.04  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.04  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR   CanUpgrade [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebApp] failed. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.07  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.07  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR   Exception: Cannot open database "ProjectWebApp" requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user 'UNDPAF\spFarmAcc'.    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.09  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.09  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OpenConnection()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseSequence.GetVersion(SPDatabase database, Guid id, Version defaultVersion, SqlSession session, SPDatabaseSequence sequence)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseSequence.GetVersion(Guid id, Version defaultVersion)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.ProjectDatabaseSequence.get_BuildVersion()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSequence.get_CanUpgrade()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CanUpgrade(Object o)  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.10  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   FullFarmDependentProjectDatabaseSequence    0000    INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.10  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   FullFarmDependentProjectDatabaseSequence    0000    WARNING Project Web Instance 'SharePoint - 80:PWA' can only be upgraded once its database 'ProjectWebApp' has been upgraded 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.13  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnf   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.13  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnf   ERROR   Cannot upgrade [ProjectSite Name=0dd67249-2882-42f9-8d3c-d44e05001826]. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.21  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.21  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR   CanUpgrade [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppPPermission] failed.  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.23  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.23  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR   Exception: Cannot open database "ProjectWebAppPPermission" requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user 'UNDPAF\spFarmAcc'. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.26  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.26  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OpenConnection()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseSequence.GetVersion(SPDatabase database, Guid id, Version defaultVersion, SqlSession session, SPDatabaseSequence sequence)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseSequence.GetVersion(Guid id, Version defaultVersion)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.ProjectDatabaseSequence.get_BuildVersion()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSequence.get_CanUpgrade()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CanUpgrade(Object o)  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.28  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   FullFarmDependentProjectDatabaseSequence    0000    INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.28  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   FullFarmDependentProjectDatabaseSequence    0000    WARNING Project Web Instance 'SharePoint - 80:PWAP' can only be upgraded once its database 'ProjectWebAppPPermission' has been upgraded 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.29  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnf   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.29  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnf   ERROR   Cannot upgrade [ProjectSite Name=2008d714-0a4e-4ab5-90a1-06fd36e0c8dd]. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.37  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.37  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR   CanUpgrade [ProjectDatabase Name=ProjectWebAppTestA] failed.    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.40  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.40  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR   Exception: Cannot open database "ProjectWebAppTestA" requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user 'UNDPAF\spFarmAcc'.   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.42  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.42  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxme   ERROR      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OpenConnection()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseSequence.GetVersion(SPDatabase database, Guid id, Version defaultVersion, SqlSession session, SPDatabaseSequence sequence)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDatabaseSequence.GetVersion(Guid id, Version defaultVersion)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.ProjectDatabaseSequence.get_BuildVersion()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSequence.get_CanUpgrade()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CanUpgrade(Object o)  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.45  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   FullFarmDependentProjectDatabaseSequence    0000    INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.45  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   FullFarmDependentProjectDatabaseSequence    0000    WARNING Project Web Instance 'SharePoint - 80:PWATest' can only be upgraded once its database 'ProjectWebAppTestA' has been upgraded    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.46  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnf   INFO    PsiServiceApplication Name=Project Service Application  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
04/18/2015 13:29:42.46  PSCONFIG (0x4080)   0x1AE8  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxnf   ERROR   Cannot upgrade [ProjectSite Name=71c39858-23fc-4882-8704-015060000928]. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be a **permission problem**. (by taking a look at your log).

> Cannot open database "ProjectWebAppPPermission", Login failed for user UNDPAF\spFarmAcc

[image: Cannot Open database]

[image]

Check the permissions and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Their are two issues as per the logs:

1. 1st one is the warnning from the old features(NintexLiveAdminLinks), which is avaible in your DBs but not avaiable in farm. But this is warnning and never fail you upgrade.
2. Major Shop Stopper is Your **UNDPAF\spFarmAcc** does not have the DBO rights on the **ProjectWebApp, ProjectWebAppPPermission and ProjectWebAppTestA**. Make Sure Your Farm Admin account (spFarmAcc) have DBO rights in SQL Server.